# How to make API call every 2 seconds if previous API call (the same one) returned an error?

Tags: api, vue.js, setinterval

It's a Vue.js app.

Everything starts by clicking button "Save" and inside saving process I need to make API call every 2 seconds if previous API call (the same one) returned an error 402.

The crucial part of code looks as following:

```
methods: {
  save() {
    ...
    Promise.all([updateOrder])
      .then(async values => {
        for (let payment of values[0].payments) {
          if ((payment.payment_type === 10 || payment.payment_type === 11) && payment.status === 0) {
            this.$axios.get(
              `${this.$config.server}/api/crm/payments/qr/${payment.id}/url`
              )
              .then(response => {
                //
              })
              .catch(error => {
                const response = error.response ?? error
                const errorCode = response?.data?.code // It returned error 402
              })
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(
        //
      )
      ...
  }
}
```

I suppose I should use:

```
setInterval(apiCall(payment), 2000)
```

But, I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved in many ways depending on your code logic. The simplest way is to use `setTimeout`, but you will need to put that call in a separate function.

The following is a simulation for an API call that will be rejected 3 times in a row and how to handle a rejection with `setTimeout`.

```js
let counter = 0

const apiCall = () => counter > 3 ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject()

const apiHandler = () => {
  console.log('Call num:', ++counter)
  apiCall()
    .then(() => console.log('Approved'))
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('Rejected')
      setTimeout(apiHandler, 2000)
    })
}

apiHandler()
```

Another advance solution is [axios-retry](https://github.com/softonic/axios-retry) since you use axios for you API calls. Here is an example of what your code might look like:

```js
methods: {
  save() {
    ...
    // Better to move this line to main.js file or 
    // to use custom axios instance (axios.create()) 
    // in case you want to apply axios-retry to this API call only 
    axiosRetry(this.$axios, { retries: 0 });

    const retryOptions = {
      retries: 10,
      retryDelay: () => 2000,
      retryCondition: (error) => {
        return error.response.status === 402
      },
    }

    Promise.all([updateOrder])
      .then(async values => {
        for (let payment of values[0].payments) {
          if ((payment.payment_type === 10 || payment.payment_type === 11) && payment.status === 0) {
            this.$axios.get(
              `${this.$config.server}/api/crm/payments/qr/${payment.id}/url`,
      {'axios-retry': retryOptions}
              )
              .then(response => {
                //
              })
              .catch(error => {
                const response = error.response ?? error
                const errorCode = response?.data?.code // It returned error 402
              })
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(
        //
      )
      ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the possible solutions. Is it possible to achieve it by using setInterval?

Comment: No worries. It's possible but its kinda less practical. Moreover, you will need to cancel the timer using `clearInerval`  once the call is succeeded.